# Why is the call to requestAnimationFrame(render) commonly put at the top of a render function which thereby calls itself recursively?

Tags: javascript, rendering

I have seen it in many examples and often even official docs that use `requestAnimationFrame` in some form. For example:

```
var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

why is `requestAnimationFrame` here put **on top** in the function body? To me it seems this could possibly cause congestion of the call stack or execution environment, because what happens if the `render` function is called by `requestAnimationFrame` **before** the rest of its function body has finished executing because the next animation frame became available?? (And the same for all subsequent calls, clogging things up)

To me it intuitively seems more sane to put the `requestAnimationFrame(render);` statement as the **last** statement of the function body. So this way the rest of the function is always guaranteed to have finished execution until another call to the render function is made.

Is there some internal mechanism I am missing or misunderstand and is putting it at the top actually the recommended approach or why is it seen so often? Please help me understand, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `render` function will not be called before the current frame has been displayed, which will only occur after the current call to `render` has returned.

Let's say you are currently computing the nth frame. When you call `requestAnimationFrame`,the given callback is queued in the (n+1)th frame's queue. Next frame will be processed only after the current frame has been displayed.

[This post](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4#.kq3bv8tlz) pretty well describes the frames lifecycle and its relation to `requestAnimationFrame`.